# Which countries have provisions for e-summons (e-mail, whatsapp, fax, etc.)? Please share specific guidelines, rules, news articles would also work

Tags: civil-procedure, criminal-procedure, electronic-procedure

I'm researching electronic summons, which are served electronically through e-mail, messaging services, fax, etc. Although I have found guidelines from some Indian states, I'm looking for e-summon rules and procedures from global-north countries. Please share specific guidelines, rules, and news articles would also work.

Answer (score 2):

### [Substituted Service](https://www.legalaid.nsw.gov.au/my-problem-is-about/my-money/making-a-claim/step-by-step-guide-serving-a-statement-of-claim#accordion-85c2218b56-item-95c8b3c073)

None of the prescribed methods of service is electronic.

However, if it is proving impractical to use a standard form of service, you may apply to the court for substituted service. This can be whatever you can think of that the court accepts - email, Facebook etc.